# What is (or was) the "international frequency"?

Tags: military, aviation-history, radio-communications

I have recently read a book about Douglas BADER. This pilot has lost his legs (because of accident in 1931) but after (thanks to his single-mindedness) he takes up the "broomstick" again and became a ace with ~30 victory...
After he is shot and captured by the enemy: the Germans. Germans contact the UK in the *"International frequency"* to send prostheses. The Germans propose a deal but the RAF drops it during a bombing raid with 11 messerschmitt shot in the process.(at the same time)

What information are available about this frequency? (name, usage, frequency).

Have you question about this story?
Bonus :
[image: douglas bader]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the source of that story

Comment: the page on the book?

Comment: So what do you want to know? What is the frequency? Who invent the frequency? Which side use this frequency? Etc. please state your question clearly.

Comment: @L'aviateur: Which book is that?

Comment: This is about HISTORY, not aviation.  That said, any shortwave news broadcast would be monitored in Great Britain, so putting the request on the news program would be sufficient.

Comment: it's not nice to edit and delete a lot of sentence and additional information

Comment: Your question need some editing. In english double punctuations ("?", ":", ";",) need space AFTER and not before, paragraphs must begin with new line. Your question could be simplified as "I read somewhere that during WWII Germans contacted UK on international frequency in order to [...]" followed by your question.

Comment: You can change the ponctuation if you want i have not enderstand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The international distress frequency has been 500 kHz, since 1908.
Copious details are at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/500_kHz.

During the war, this frequency was used for reporting distress and for monitoring distress, by the [Germans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luftwaffe_radio_equipment_of_World_War_II#Emergency_navigation_aids) and the [British](https://books.google.com/books?id=jJWoFpYqGocC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=british+radio++500+khz+distress&source=bl&ots=DqGBR3Uoel&sig=ACfU3U18LRmjjcBp2gvxQ_S7hU5qUu2nqw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpxNDqqsDoAhUSG80KHe8nCdkQ6AEwEXoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=british%20radio%20%20500%20khz%20distress&f=false).  It was also used before and after the war for this purpose, by many countries, by aviators and mariners and others.

Comment: Is The communication  possible between uk and germans during the war on this frequency?